# Kubernetes double IP in different nodes

Tags: kubernetes

after using k8s on GKE for a couple of months  I've decided to install my own cluster. Now, I've two ubuntu VMs and one of them is the kube-master and the second one is a node. Cluster run as I expect and I can see nodes (kube-master is a node also) when run `kubectl get nodes`. I've launched one pod each VMs bat I'm experiencing an issue both pod have the same IP. Can anybody help me to resolve this issue? I'm using `flannel` as network plugin atm.
Thanks in advance

**Update**

I've found the solution, thanks kubernetes group on slack. I didn't install the `[cni][1]`plugin so the `kubelet` didn't know the subnetwork status. I installed the plugin using [this guide](https://medium.com/@SystemMining/setup-kubenetes-cluster-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-kubeadm-336f4061d929), made a configuration file following [that](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml). Restarted the `kubelete` service finally I saw the cluster was work as I expected.

Comment: Can you share the result of these commands?  `kubectl get endpoinds' and 'kubectl get pods`.

Comment: @SureshVishnoi thank you for the quick response. I've found the solution and amended the question. Hope this can help other people.